# Reorder time series into a custom 'quasi-chronological' order

Tags: r, sorting, time-series, lubridate

I have been searching for a way to sort my time series by a custom month order (March - February) instead of alphabetical, chronological, by year, etc. I want to maintain the year and I have about 60 years of data, so I can't just sort by month. I have tried converting to factor and sorting and that did not work. Here is a snippet of my data:

```
    Date       GageFlow  Month
1 1955-10-01     0.00     10
2 1955-10-02     0.00     10
3 1955-10-03     0.00     10
4 1955-10-04     0.00     10
```

So ideally, I'd want the time series to start 1956-03-01 and cycle through each day, month, year beginning with March instead of October. In other words, the dates should be ordered from March 1955 to Dec 1955, followed by Jan to Feb 1955, followed by March-Dec 1956 etc...

Comment: I don't follow. What do you want for an output? The sort order is the same whether the year starts on March or starts on January.

Comment: is sort by `(month-3) %% 12` what you mean? I.e. March 1955 - Dec 1955, followed by Jan-Feb 1955, followed by March-Dec 1956 etc...

Comment: If so `  df$Month2 = `(Month-3) %% 12; arrange(df, Year, Month2)`   should do it

Comment: @dww yes that is exactly what I want.  When I try your line, I receive an error regarding "Year."  I see that arrange is pulling from plyr... does "Year" need to be it's own column or formatted as a lubridate/posit vector? Message: Error in order(Year, Month2) : object 'Year' not found

Comment: @thelatemail. I don't see why I was voted down for this question.  Yes, what I want is the df sorted such that the first month is March, not October. It makes a difference because I am doing statistics on an annual basis, where the Year is March-February.

Comment: @LauraR - why do people keep assuming I downvote whenever I ask for clarification? Again, it wasn't me! :-P I imagine the downvotes might have been because the question wasn't all that clear initially. It is an interesting one though, now that I know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @LauraR, yes, code in the comment assumed that you create a column for Year, as you did for Month. I show in answer below how to do exactly same as this, but without creating extra columns if you prefer. Note, also that I edited your question to incorporate the clarification from the above comments. The original wording was rather unclear. Please double check that it is now what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the following code I generated a dummy dataframe with 2 years data:

```
Date <- seq(as.Date("1955/1/1"), as.Date("1956/12/31"), by = "day")
GageFlow <- round(runif(731),2)
df <- data.frame(Date, GageFlow, stringsAsFactors = F)

head(df)
        Date GageFlow
1 1955-01-01     0.25
2 1955-01-02     0.51
3 1955-01-03     0.13
4 1955-01-04     0.46
5 1955-01-05     0.35
6 1955-01-06     0.20
```

The following code rearranges it according to March being the first month
and February the last.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
# Create month variable
df$month <- month(df$Date)

# Create scaled month variable
df$month_new <- df$month - 2
df$month_new <- ifelse(df$month_new == -1 , 11, 
                       ifelse(df$month_new == 0, 12, df$month_new))

# Rearrange the dataframe    
df2 <- df %>% arrange(year(Date), month_new, day(Date)) %>% select(-month_new)
```

The dataset has now the following configuration:

```
head(df2)
        Date GageFlow month
1 1955-03-01     0.99     3
2 1955-03-02     0.98     3
3 1955-03-03     0.97     3
4 1955-03-04     0.60     3
5 1955-03-05     0.43     3
6 1955-03-06     0.28     3
```

Zooming in to the transition between December and January:

```
df2[305:309,]
          Date GageFlow month
305 1955-12-30     0.91    12
306 1955-12-31     0.64    12
307 1955-01-01     0.25     1
308 1955-01-02     0.51     1
309 1955-01-03     0.13     1
```

Zooming in to the transition between February and March of the following year:

```
df2[364:367,]
          Date GageFlow month
364 1955-02-27     0.46     2
365 1955-02-28     0.40     2
366 1956-03-01     0.81     3
367 1956-03-02     0.73     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo operator `%%` together with an offset to convert months into a custom ordering. To demonstrate:

Some dummy data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=seq(as.Date("1955/1/1"), as.Date("1956/12/31"), by = "day"))
```

Now arrange into custom order

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)    
df <- arrange(df, year(Date), (month(Date)-3) %% 12)
```

NB the above assumes that dates start off in ascending "standard" chronological order.  If the rows are not ordered at the outset, then you will also need to add the day of the month to the `arrange`.

```
df <- arrange(df, year(Date), (month(Date)-3) %% 12, day(Date))
```